How to push cassandra application metrices in springboot?
I'm planning to push cassandra application metrices to prometheus. while surfing on internet, refered this link.  I'm planning to fetch these cassandra application metrices i.e.,caller clientip, db query and time taken by the query.
Can you provide any suggestions or samples to integrate cassandra metrices in prometheus ?

add spring boot actuator, configure prometheus. Done.

Did the same. Able to fetch some of the cassandra  db metrics like low cardinality keys. But unable to fetch low cardinality keys like db_statement. Do I need to configure anything explicitly to fectch db_statement ?

No those should be available, you are actually using the version you are referring to? Also isn't it db.statement? Which metrics do you see are those actually the Spring Data ones or the regular Cassandra ones (as that has metrics as well!).

yes it is db.statement and I have mentioned in the prometheus format. I'm seeing the metrics in this format  db_operation="SELECT",db_system="cassandra", spring_data_cassandra_methodName="execute",spring_data_cassandra_sessionName="s0"

The db.statement is a high-cardinality key, which isn't propagated as a metric only in traces/spans. If you really want this as a low-cardinality key you would need to create your custom cassandra observation (basically extending the original one and modify the behavior).

Can you please provide some samples to create a custom cassandra metric in springboot application to fetch the query ?

You don't need a custom metric it is already there you only need to make sure it is a low cardinality tag instead of high. You can extend the existing cassandra observation from Spring and add the behavior and wire that up in the cassandra configuration.

Looking at the code that might be harder then expected. The CassandraObservationConvention interface is the one you want a custom implementation for, however all the places using the CassandraObservationConvention don't allow for it to be changed.

@M.Deinum.. Thanks a lot for the info. Can you please let me know how we can convert a high cardinality value to low cardinality value in springboot?

No as that currently isn't possible for this, not without re-writing the whole infrastructure. Issue a enhancement request to allow for wiring the CassandraObservationConvention instead of creating it.

Can you please let me know how we can issue a enhance request to allow wiring CassandraObservationConvention ?

Go to the github repository for spring cassandra.

Thanks a lot Denium .. Have raised an issue for the same git repo .
